# Wrapfigure is not producing figure

Tags: pdftex, wrapfigure

My code is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfigure}
\newtheorem{problem}{P}[chapter]
\begin{document}
A circle is drawn in a sector of a larger circle
\begin{problem}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{TrigFig23.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
of radius $r$, as shown in the adjacent figure. 
The smaller circle is tangent to the two bounding radii and the arc of the sector. Find the radius of the smaller circle.
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

This code is not producing figure at all (neither it is showing error). I have used `wrapfig` package as well. Please help!!

Comment: have you tried to use a PNG oder JPEG file instead of PDF?

Comment: No. I usually use the pdf. I am unable to find any reason why it is not working with pdf.

Comment: @Micha I tried PNG just now, it is too not working.

Comment: @campa I got the reason: I am using this code inside the `problem` environment which I defined using `newtheorem`. This code is working without `problem` environment, but I want to use it inside it. Please give suggestions.

Comment: @campa I am really sorry for not realizing that my code is not minimally working. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @your MWE doesn't work. Missed are some package or have wrong names. Please correct it and test it before loading in question.

Comment: If I replace the wrong `wrapfigure` with `wrapfig` and add the `graphicx` package, the code compiles, but results in a warning "wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment".

Comment: And also the warning "Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float". The picture *does* appear below the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two minipages instead of `wrapfig`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newtheorem{problem}{P}[chapter]
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
A circle is drawn in a sector of a larger circle of radius $r$, as shown in the adjacent figure. 
The smaller circle is tangent to the two bounding radii and the arc of the sector. Find the radius of the smaller circle.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant layout, with the `insbox` set of plain TeX macros package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox}
\newtheorem{problem}{P}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\leavevmode%
\InsertBoxR{-1}{\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{example-image}}\par\noindent
A circle is drawn in a sector of a larger circle of radius $r$, as shown in the adjacent figure.
The smaller circle is tangent to the two bounding radii and the arc of the sector. Find the radius of the smaller circle.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the "problem" is a conflicting environment which prevents figure placement there, and "wrapfigure" get placed at the beginning of paragraphs, you can provide a fake paragraph with `~~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{problem}{P}[chapter]
\begin{document}
A circle is drawn in a sector of a larger circle

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
~~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{problem}
\noindent
of radius $r$, as shown in the adjacent figure. 
The smaller circle is tangent to the two bounding radii and the 
arc of the sector. Find the radius of the smaller circle.
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```